Jenkins Error: WorkflowScript: 65: unexpected token: } @ line 65, column 1. Code Line does not exist
Hello deer human beings
I have a Pipeline running on docker, with it i want to build 2 images.
but everytime i run it i get this error:
Started by user Elias Spycher

Checking out git https://github.com/Raisybear/cards_against_humanity into /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cards_against_humanity_pipeline@script/e46138fc9cf8660b857590cb378b6696fff12b52d585f68b61e8f5072062f6a5 to read Jenkinsfile
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cards_against_humanity_pipeline@script/e46138fc9cf8660b857590cb378b6696fff12b52d585f68b61e8f5072062f6a5/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Raisybear/cards_against_humanity # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Raisybear/cards_against_humanity
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.39.5'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/Raisybear/cards_against_humanity +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 6dbd5f7a38d90da89675e6bc38f19f33c7f4c92a (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 6dbd5f7a38d90da89675e6bc38f19f33c7f4c92a # timeout=10
Commit message: "Update Jenkinsfile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 6dbd5f7a38d90da89675e6bc38f19f33c7f4c92a # timeout=10
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 65: unexpected token: } @ line 65, column 1.
   }
   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:349)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:966)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:626)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox$Scope.parse(GroovySandbox.java:163)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:190)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:175)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:652)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:598)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-job//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:446)
Finished: FAILURE


And at this point i don't know any further, then the line 65 does not exist in my Jenkinsfile. The last line is 63.
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        BACKEND_IMAGE = "backend_image"
        FRONTEND_IMAGE = "frontend_image"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/Raisybear/cards_against_humanity'
            }
        }   
  
        stage('Backend Build') {
            steps {
                dir('Game/cards_against_humanity_backend') {
                    script {
                        sh 'docker build -t ${BACKEND_IMAGE} .'  // Baut das Docker-Image für das Backend.
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Frontend Build') {
            steps {
                dir('Game/cards_against_humanity_frontend') {
                    script {
                        sh 'docker build -t ${FRONTEND_IMAGE} .'  // Baut das Docker-Image für das Frontend.
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                // Tests im Backend-Verzeichnis ausführen
                dir('Game/cards_against_humanity_backend') {
                    sh 'dotnet test'  // Führt die Backend-Tests aus.
                }
                // Tests im Frontend-Verzeichnis ausführen
                dir('Game/cards_against_humanity_frontend') {
                    sh 'npm install && npm test'  // Führt die Frontend-Tests aus.
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy with Docker Compose') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d'  // Startet die Container im Hintergrund.
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            sh 'docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down'  // Stoppt und entfernt die Container nach Abschluss der Pipeline.
        }
    }
}

I am german, so just ignore the comments, the repository link is in the Error message...
I tried many diverent versions of the Jenkinsfile, added error messages, echoes, debugging steps, but everything resulted in this error shown above. The echoes were also never printed, so i think something is messed up outside the Jenkinsfile.
I would be so happy if you'd help me.

try steps { script { dir(. For example stage('Run Tests') has no script { block. I put script {
evweyehre, so it's always stage { steps { script {. Also post { always { script { sh ".... Also what I do, is I also just remove stages one by one until I find the error line.

You are not executing the Jenkinsfile you posted. According to your log your pipeline comes from commit 6dbd5f7a38d90da89675e6bc38f19f33c7f4c92a and it has too many closing brackets here.
